# Python not progressing a list of links

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, data-cleaning

So, as i need more detailed data I have to dig a bit deeper in the HTML code of a website. I wrote a script that returns me a list of specific links to detail pages, but I can't bring Python to search each link of this list for me, it always stops at the first one. What am I doing wrong?

```
 from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
 import urllib2
 from lxml import html
 import requests

 #Open site
 html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.sitetoscrape.ch/somesite.aspx")

#Inform BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)

#Search for the specific links
for link in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('/d/part/of/thelink/ineed.aspx')):
    #print found links
    print link.get('href')
    #complete links
    complete_links = 'http://www.sitetoscrape.ch' + link.get('href')
    #print complete links
    print complete_links
#
#EVERYTHING WORKS FINE TO THIS POINT
#

page = requests.get(complete_links)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

#Details
name = tree.xpath('//dl[@class="services"]')

for i in name:
    print i.text_content()
```

Also: What tutorial can you recommend me to learn how to put my output in a file and clean it up, give variable names, etc?

Comment: Your `GET` request using `complete_links` is not inside the for loop, so it will only run once with the last value `complete_links` took on before exiting the loop

Comment: you are overwriting `complete_links` at every loop, is it correct? Or would you want a list of links instead?

Comment: Is it somehow possible that `complete_links` is seen as a list of values  that get checked?

Comment: Why would you use both `requests` and `urllib2`? Why would you use both `BeautifulSoup` and `lxml`? I find it very confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want a list of links in `complete_links` instead of a *single* link. As @Pynchia and @lemonhead said you're overwritting `complete_links` every iteration of first for loop.

You need two changes:

- Append links to a list and use it to loop and scrap each link

  ```
  # [...] Same code here

  links_list = []
  for link in soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('/d/part/of/thelink/ineed.aspx')):
      print link.get('href')
      complete_links = 'http://www.sitetoscrape.ch' + link.get('href')
      print complete_links
      link_list.append(complete_links)  # append new link to the list
  ```
- Scrap each accumulated link in another loop

  ```
  for link in link_list:
      page = requests.get(link)
      tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

      #Details
      name = tree.xpath('//dl[@class="services"]')

      for i in name:
          print i.text_content()
  ```

PS: I recommend [scrapy framework](http://scrapy.org/) for tasks like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will definitly take some time to look into the scrapy documentation!